# UseExceptionHandler is being ignored

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

This is my Startup() method in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        loggerFactory.AddNLog();
    }

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry(); // Needs to be first
    app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp =>
    {
        errorApp.Run(async context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

            var error = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            if (error != null)
            {
                var ex = error.Error;

                await context.Response.WriteAsync(new ErrorResponse
                {
                    Code = 500,
                    Message = ex.Message
                }.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
            }
        });
    });
    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry(); // After error page
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

This is my route in a controller.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Test")]
public string Test()
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Query["test"]))
        throw new Exception("Testing..");

    return "Hello.";
}
```

**ErrorResponse.cs**

```
public class ErrorResponse
{
    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

When I go to http://website/test it shows "Hello." but when I go to http://website/test?test=asd it throws my exception (the one in the route) instead of catching it with UseExceptionHandler and stops the program.

My goal is to make it show the following json instead:

```
{
    "Error": 500,
    "Message": "Testing..."
}
```

I am using asp.net core.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: @StinkyTowel Woops, it's throwing my own exception instead of passing it through UseExceptionHandler. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Does anything handle it?  Do you have an application_error method setup in global.asax to catch these?

Comment: Check this out as well - https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/03/23/aspnet-core-tips-and-tricks-global-exception-handling/

Comment: mm..maybe not fully understand the problem - you run app using VS and app is stopped on exception?  If so this is because Debugger is attached. Run app from console for example (or disable break on exception in VS)

Comment: @Set That was the issue.. running it from cmd with `dotnet run` makes the page appear. Weird.. thought I tested that before. Thanks!

Comment: I have the problem described on question although, in my case, razor page runtime exceptions are correctly handled by the handler, but any runtime exceptions in controllers doesn't hit the handler and just output the raw exception (and it's not the developer exception page style).. Very confusing - have tried lots of things without any success yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your app is stopped on exception cause you run it in debug mode in VS and Debugger is attached. Run app from console for example (or disable "break on exception" option in VS.

Comment: This is entirely incorrect. The app is NOT being stopped on exception when the debugger is attached. It enters the break mode, which is different. After hitting F5 the execution continues as it would when there is no debugger attached. The reason for the OP issue is that something else in the execution pipeline is interfering with exception handling and setting the response result, hence the `UseExceptionHandler` is being ignored.

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was that `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()` was already catching the exceptions and conflicting in some way with this middleware.

Comment: Why would you expect that both would work together, given that they both do the same thing?

Comment: If I would have known that: first, our startup code had been using that exception handling (UseDeveloperExceptionPage) only for dev environment, and second that they both use the same UseExceptionHandler, I've even not been searching this issue. If I've could have read my own answer I would have found the solution in less than 1 minute, so probably my answer is useful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but I just hit the same issue.

There is likely some exception filter applied globally. Look up the MVC configuration in `Startup.ConfigureServices`. I had `services.AddMvcOptions(o => o.Filters.Add<ErrorHandlerAttribute>())` which was the problem.

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: I have the problem described on question, but can't find any of these conflicts mentioned in this answer.. But this feels like the right explanation - anything I might be missing to check for? In my case, razor page runtime exceptions are correctly handled by the handler, but any runtime exceptions in controllers doesn't hit the handler and just output the raw exception (and it's not the developer exception page style).. Very confusing - have tried lots of things without any success yet.

Comment: If you can see the raw exception AND there is no `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()`, there is definitely some filter in action. See if there are extension methods to `IApplicationBuilder` that you're calling to setup something else. Maybe some 3rd party is playing low...